# How does \over work?

Tags: macros, plain-tex, fractions

I don't mean this necessarily in the sense of diving into code, but `\over` seems to function differently to other commands, which scoop up only *following* arguments.  Instead, `11\over2` gobbles up the *preceding* (as well as following) argument—and not just a *single* preceding token, but back to the beginning of the nearest group.

I know it's bad style in the modern style of coding and one *shouldn't* do such things, but is it *possible* to write such look-behind commands in Plain TeX, or is `\over` given special-cased privileges by the source?    (For what it's worth, I *did* dive casually into *TeX:  The program*, finding that `\over` and relatives look at an `incompleat_noad` and a `fraction_noad`.  That's obviously something special-cased for dealing with fractions, but can I access those noads, whatever they are, from macroland?)

(I do intentionally specify Plain TeX because I'm interested if this can be done without using e-TeX's fancy tokenising capabilities, but I don't know whether e-TeX can do it either.)

Comment: `\over`  is really the worst feature in tex, adding that one "simple" shorthand to allow infix use brings with it the entire `\mathchoice` complication and impossibility of knowing which math style you are in at any point (end rant)

Comment: the answer to your question is that `\over`, `\atop` and their `withdelims` variants are special cased in the source and similar commands can not be defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks!  Does e-TeX allow lookbehind?  (Aside from the general sentiment clearly being against it, your personal feelings are clear, but I'm still curious if it's possible even though I wouldn't.) \\ Also, would you be willing to post your comments as an answer?  I can't imagine any better response than that, and there's no point having this question hang around unanswered (unless it should just be deleted).

Comment: etex makes no difference here (most plain tex users are using pdftex so already using etex) nor xetex you could perhaps rewrite the math handling in lua so luatex is a possibility but you can not define new such commands from the tex side of luatex either

Comment: The `tokcycle` package provides the means to scan an input stream and reformulate it according to user-defined logic.  An example of look-ahead is shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575455/read-character-preceding-a-command/575464#575464

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, since plain TeX already has some clunky look-ahead capabilities, I guess (based on your [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575455/read-character-preceding-a-command/575464)) you [meant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581511/how-does-over-work#comment1462876_581511) "look-*behind*", right?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, though "ahead" and "behind" can mean different things to people based on perspective, so I thought to cover all bases.  `tokcycle` directives can be written so as to look in both directions, as long as you can formulate the logic of the governing rule.  I would note also that `tokcycle` works in Plain TeX, as well.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thanks!  How does `tokcycle` working in Plain TeX square with @‍DavidCarlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581521) that it cannot be done?  (Perhaps my vagueness in the definition of ‘it’ is the problem here.)

Comment: @LSpice `tokcycle` macros or environments read through their input stream of tokens, allowing you to analyze them one by one (without executing them) and create a new token list, which can then be executed (or processed further with some other macro).  Generally, the new token list will be some modified version of the input stream, to achieve a desired goal.  So it essentially becomes a double pass process, in which the first pass allows you to rearrange what gets executed on the 2nd pass.  So it is different than what David is referring to, which doesn't allow for the whole 2nd pass concept.

Comment: I would add, regarding `tokcycle` that what I described above is one common "use case" only.  You don't even have to create a new token list...you could just execute things, based on what you find in the input stream.  You could, alternatively, use it to count things in the input stream, so that what is output bears no resemblance to the input stream, but rather represents some analysis of the input stream.  The user specified *directives* are the instructions on "what to do" when encountering certain tokens or token types in the input stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\over`, `\atop` and their `withdelims` variants are special cased in the source and similar commands can not be defined.

The same is true in extended TeX variants `etex`, `xetex`, `pdftex`.

In Luatex you could (perhaps) define some pre or post processing using one of the Lua callbacks to give the appearance of such an infix command that collected up everything since the start of the group, but this would have to be all in the Lua side, the Tex related features would not help implement this functionality even in luatex.

Comment: @LSpice fixed ..